# how to display country code in textbox base on selection of dropdown value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Below code give me the error:
```

facebook.htmlName=&LastName=&Email=&Password=&enterEmail=&country_name=&code=&mobile=&btn2=faceboo…:203 The specified value "+,91" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>user registration form validation using javascript with example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function selectvalue(x){

            var country_dropdown=document.getElementById("country");
            var country_Mcode=document.getElementById("country_mcode");
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="1")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="+91"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="2")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="+1"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="3")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="+880"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="4")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="+81"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="5")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="+86"
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="emptyDiv">
</div>
<div id="description"></div>
<!--container start-->
<div id="container">
    <div id="container_body">
        <div>
            <h2 class="form_title">User Registration Form Demo</h2>
            <p class="head_para">Form Validated Using Javascript</p>
        </div>
        <!--Form  start-->
        <div id="form_name">
            <div class="firstnameorlastname">
                <form name="form" >
                    <div id="errorBox"></div>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  class="input_name" >
                    <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name" >

            </div>

            <div id="email_form">
                <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email">
            </div>

            <div id="password_form">
                <input type="password" name="Password" value=""  placeholder="New Password" class="input_password">
            </div>

            <div id="Re_email_form">
                <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value=""  placeholder="Re-enter Email" class="input_Re_email">
            </div>

            <!--birthday details start-->
            <div>
                <h3 class="country">Country</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name="country_name" id="country" onchange="selectvalue()">
                    <option value="" selected >Country</option>
                    <option value="1">india</option>
                    <option value="2">america</option>
                    <option value="3">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="4">japan</option>
                    <option value="5">china</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <h3 class="country">Mobile No</h3>
            </div>
            <div>

                <input type="number" name="code" value=""  class="input_name" id="country_mcode" >
            </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="mobile" value="" placeholder="Mobile No" class="input_name" >
        </div>
            <!--birthday details ends-->

        <div>
            <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()">Registration</p>
        </div>
        <div>
           <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="facebook registration"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="google_user" onClick="Submit()">Google Registration</p>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <!--form ends-->
    </div>
</div>
<!--container ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make country_mcode input type to text instead of number.  Because number does not allow + sign.

Comment: ohh !! Its working, Thank you @Jenny

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your input field is type=number and a + (plus) can not be added this way.

That is actually a little odd, because you can type in +10 for example. But then it is interpreted as a positive 10 and the + is removed and not stored in the value attribute. You can either change the type or remove the plus from the number making it a valid number and not a string.

This should be verifiable if you type +10 in your field and then use the console and type in `document.getElementById('country_mcode')[0].value`.

The returned value should be 10 not +10.

Edit:
You could remove the type enforcement and add a `pattern="\+\d{1,5}"` or something similar to allow for your specific use case if the input field can be set by user.